# Using back and next buttons for navigate between tabs - material-ui (version 0.18.7)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using material ui tabs and I'm trying to add back and next buttons to navigate between two tabs.

While doing so, I encountered an issue, when Im trying to change the value of the tabs by clicking back or next buttons the tabs doesn't change, this is my current code:

```
...

this.state = {
value: 0,
};
...

handleNextTab() {
    let value = this.state.value;
    if(value !== 1) {
    value = value + 1;
    this.setState({value: value})
    }
}

handleBackTab() {
let value = this.state.value;
    if(value !== 0) {
       value = value - 1;
       this.setState({value: value})
    }
}

handleTabChange(value) {
    this.setState({
        value: value
    });
};

handleActive(value) {
    this.setState({value: value})
}

render() {

return (
<div>
    <Tabs
        value={this.state.value}
        onChange={this.handleTabChange.bind(this)}>
        <Tab
            onActive={this.handleActive.bind(this, 0)}
            label={'page 1'} 
            value={0} 
            key={0}>
        <div>
            some code
        </div>
        </Tab>

        <Tab
            onActive={this.handleActive.bind(this, 1)}
            label={'page 2'} 
            value={1} 
            key={1}>
        <div>
            some code
        </div>
        </Tab>
    </Tabs> 

    <FlatButton
        label={'Back'}
        onTouchTap={this.handleBackTab.bind(this)}
    />
    <FlatButton
        label={'Next'}
        onTouchTap={this.handleNextTab.bind(this)}
    />
</div>
); 
}
```

Anyone has an idea why it doesn't work?

thanks for the helpers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working fine for me when i used this code instead of `FlatButton`.

```
<button onClick={this.handleBackTab.bind(this)}>Back</button>
<button onClick={this.handleNextTab.bind(this)}>Next</button>
```

I think the problem is your `FlatButton`.

Use `onClick` instead of `onTouchTab`.

```
<FlatButton
        label={'Back'}
        onClick={this.handleBackTab.bind(this)}
    />
    <FlatButton
        label={'Next'}
        onClick={this.handleNextTab.bind(this)}
    />
```

I couldn't find `onTouchTab` in the documentation.
Reference link: https://v0.material-ui.com/#/components/flat-button

Comment: thanks for your answer!
I tried doing this but it didn't work for me.