# Using back and next buttons for navigate between tabs - headlessUI (version 1.4.2)

Tags: reactjs, headless-ui

We are using the components from headlessUI(https://headlessui.dev/react/tabs) in on of our react projects. We need to put buttons into the tabs of the tabs component, so we can open the next tab with a button. Similar to this problem here [Using back and next buttons for navigate between tabs - material-ui (version 0.18.7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55608339/using-back-and-next-buttons-for-navigate-between-tabs-material-ui-version-0-1)

We tried to find a solution online and tried to use the props of the componentes.

Does someone got a similar problem in the past or knows how we can handle this problem?